# Tableau - % of Unique Metric by Different Unique Metric

Tags: tableau-api

I have Customer ID, Product ID, and Industry columns.  For example:

```
 **CustomerID  ProductID  Industry**
    1          A          Entertainment
    1          B          Entertainment
    2          A          Entertainment
    3          A          Entertainment
    4          A          Entertainment
    4          B          Entertainment
    4          A          Cleaning
```

I have a grid set up with industry for my columns and Product ID for my rows.

For example,

```
  Entertainment  Cleaning
A
B
```

I'm trying to find the % of customers in a specific industry purchasing each product.

In other words the (number of unique customers by Product ID)/(Unique customers in each industry).

The numerator is: COUNTD([Customer ID])
The denominator is throwing me off.  I'm not sure how to get unique customers in a segment.

In the example above, product A has 4 unique customers in the Entertainment industry, and Entertainment has 4 unique customers for all products, so the calculation for product A would 4/4 or 100%.

But product B would be 2 unique customers / 4 total unique customers in Entertainment or 50%.

Does anyone know how I create the calculation for the denominator.

COUNTD([Customer ID])/???

Comment: Can you attach a sample file?

Comment: Not sure, but I would try to do it this way COUNTD([Customer ID])/{EXCLUDE [ProductID] : COUNTD([Customer ID])}